# how to use on resume method()?

Tags: android

help me  to do this, i have button image  it should be unselected,when i click it should be selected if i go next activity and if i come back it should be selected,if i was not selected before going next activity it should be unselected.how can i do this i have 32 buttons totally in activity 1.

```
dwn15=(Button)findViewById(R.id.adultdwn15);
dwn15.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      public void onClick(View view){
        if(teeth[30]==0){
           dwn15.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.adultdwn15);          
           teeth[30]=31;
        }
        else{

          dwn15.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.adultdwn15_pressed);       

          teeth[30]=0;
        }
      }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try selector like this:

```
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "utf-8" ?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/selectable_image" />
<item android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@drawable/selectable_image" />
<item android:state_selected = "true" android:drawable = "@drawable/selectable_image" />
<item android:drawable = "@drawable/default_image" />
</selector>
```

set this selector in place of image to your button and on button click put `button.setSelected("true")`.

Answer (score 0):

You could prevent your activities from entering onCreate() every time you pass to another activity and come back. This can be done from manifest with the help of launchMode. [Here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html)
is a link.

Another way to implement this is to keep an array of boolean for your buttons where you keep if a button was selected.